# numpy / python - indexing by arrays with duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to make a 3D histogram. Initially `h = zeros((6,6,8))`. 
I'll explain my problem with an example. Suppose I have 3 lists of coordinates for `h`, each list for one dimension: 
`x = array([2,1,0,1,2,2])`
`y = array([1,3,0,3,2,1])`
`z = array([6,2,0,2,5,6])` (the coordinates `(x[0],y[0],z[0])` and `(x[6],y[6],z[6])` are duplicates, and `(x[1],y[1],z[1])` and `(x[3],y[3],z[3])` also are)
and also a list of corresponding quantities to accumulate into `h`:
`q = array([1,2,5,9,8,7])`

I tried and `h[x,y,z] += q` does not work because only `q[5] = 7` is added to `h[2,1,6]` and `q[0] = 1` is not.

How can I work around this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want [`np.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html).  To quote the docs: "For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once."

For example:

```
>>> np.add.at(h, [x,y,z], q)
>>> for i, val in np.ndenumerate(h):
...     if val: print(i, val)
...     
((0, 0, 0), 5.0)
((1, 3, 2), 11.0)
((2, 1, 6), 8.0)
((2, 2, 5), 8.0)
```